# Change font size inside only one line of document

Tags: fontsize, article

My `article` is written using 11 pt font, but I would like to write a line in **bold** using a size which is bigger than 11.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\begin{document}
\par
~
\par
\noindent
% I want to enlarge only this statement
\textbf{Analisi fluidodinamica su Stramazzo Generico}
% this is the text
Si immagini che un fluido perfetto e incomprimibile... 
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: is the line simply part of regular text, or do you know its start and end ahead of time?  if it's already on a line by itself, you could use `{\large\bfseries ...}` to do the job.

Comment: I'm thinking you'll need the `soul` package here???

Comment: I have just reported some code in the question

Comment: It's not really clear why the part should be in a larger font. Are you perhaps trying to emulate `\subsection` or something similar?

Comment: @egreg I intend to create something like `\subsection` but without any number at the beginning of the statement

Comment: @Cybex `\subsection*`

Comment: egreg's suggestion is best.  But if you did need to enlarge some text in a different setting, as in your MWE, you could say `\textbf{\large text to be made bigger} normal sized text`.

Comment: Little tip. When showing any particular problem, it's advisable to use [a Minimum Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe): it keeps the code clean from any package interference and limits the problem search area

Comment: @egreg Do you want to add an answer? Or close?

Comment: @Johannes_B Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to emulate `\subsection`, but without a number, just do

```
\subsection*{Analisi fluidodinamica su Stramazzo Generico}
```

If you just have numbered sections, but not subsections, add

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
```

to your preamble and use

```
\subsection{Analisi fluidodinamica su Stramazzo Generico}
```

with the advantage that the subsections can go directly to the table of contents (provided `tocdepth` is set to 2 or more).